# Extending a generic type with a constructor function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

How to extend a generic type with a constructor function in Typescript?

```
function doSomething<T extends ?constructor?>(constructor: T) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any;

class Base {
  baseProp = 'base value';
}

function doSomething<T extends Constructor>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
      factoryProp = 'factory prop';
    }
}

const DerivedClass = doSomething(Base);

const instance = new DerivedClass;

console.log(instance.baseProp);
console.log(instance.factoryProp);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigQgHcoAKAOmoENUBzJALihoRAG0BdASgID5W7ANwAoUZgA2NJEigAhGdADeoqFABGSgAqo4YAlADkWpNABuNSeghGxAX3EAzdAmwBLRFAAmcAMpwALYQwAAW7gj0ADwAKlAQAB7AEAjecvDIaFg4qPzkmIgoGNi4LDF8qurqqCHoqAhQUjJyicmpcgWZxTlQlVXqTjQlqCC6%20oZGg8MgUGB6YHZqVY6OEoXAUAAiEKju5hDeMNKyhr4BwWER9OSKZjxia5lQEShsmNCExGTbu-uHx0gHp0kHBJBBKJI4NcXsA3uDTBAxmB7o8QWCIVDyDC4ZQpjlRvN7kA)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it, I've needed it for similar case, only with decorators :)